# How can I create a virtual summation field by entity

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have records which have a sq. mileage field. I want to sum these fields by date, so regardless of display page, order, etc. the value by entity will be the same.
e.g.:

```
|id|   date   |sqmiles|total|
|--|----------|-------|-----|
|1 |2010-10-10|   2   |  2  |
|2 |2011-11-11|   3   |  5  |
|3 |2012-12-12|   1   |  6  |
```

```
|id|   date   |sqmiles|total|
|--|----------|-------|-----|
|3 |2012-12-12|   1   |  6  |
|1 |2010-10-10|   2   |  2  |
|2 |2011-11-11|   3   |  5  |
```

My starting thoughts were a virtual field where it requests the following SQL:
`SELECT SUM(sq_miles) FROM table WHERE date <= ($this->_properties['date']);` but with CakePHP3's new ORM I don't know how to put that into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the "best" answer, but I made it work:
In the entity add `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` then the following function:

```php
    protected function _getTotalSqMiles()
    {
        $annexations = TableRegistry::get('Annexations');
        $query = $annexations->find();
        $sum = $query->func()->sum('sq_miles');
        $results = $query->select(['total' => $sum])
            ->where([
                'effective_date <=' => $this->_properties['effective_date']
            ])
            ->first();
        return $results->total;
    }
```